# Change color of Datagrid Column using Value of other column

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

```
<DataGrid>
 <DataGrid.Columns>

 <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" >
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label x:Name="lblName" Content="{Binding Name}" Foreground="White" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=IsActice}" Header="Is Actice"  />
 </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I want to Change the Color of lblName when Datagrid Fills according to IsActive Value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved using the following code

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}" x:Key="DataGridLabel">
  <Style.Triggers>
    <MultiDataTrigger>
      <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsActive}" Value="False"/>
      </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
      <Setter Property="Label.Background" Value="Red"/>
    </MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger>
      <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsActive}" Value="True"/>
      </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
      <Setter Property="Label.Background" Value="Green"/>
    </MultiDataTrigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `DataContext` is the same everywhere: The whole current row.

You can easily add a `Style` to the `Label` and use a [`DataTrigger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatrigger.aspx) on `IsActive`. (If you intend to have a default color that needs to be moved to a `Setter` in the `Style` due to [precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.100%29.aspx))

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Converter (Active variable's datatype to Color) with return type Color and attach it to Label. Based on Active value, converter will return desired color.